# Finding all groups of contiguous words in string

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to find all groups of two contiguous words in a string, but only of words that have 2-3 chars of length. So far I've come with this:

```
'toolong fee fi fo fum toolong verylong aa bb'.scan(/\b[a-z]{2,3}\s+\b[a-z]{2,3}/)
=> ["fee fi", "fo fum", "aa bb"]
```

But I want something like this:

```
=> ["fee fi", "fi fo", "fo fum", "aa bb"]
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lookahead along with capturing group in-order to do overlapping matches.

```
> 'toolong fee fi fo fum toolong verylong aa bb'.scan(/(?=\b([a-z]{2,3}\s+[a-z]{2,3})\b)/)
=> [["fee fi"], ["fi fo"], ["fo fum"], ["aa bb"]]
> 'toolong fee fi fo fum toolong verylong aa bb'.scan(/\b(?=([a-z]{2,3}\s+[a-z]{2,3})\b)/).flatten
=> ["fee fi", "fi fo", "fo fum", "aa bb"]
```

Comment: A little improvement to move the first `\b` outside. `\b(?=`... not necessary to look ahead at each position.

Comment: I like this one, thanks! As a minor simplification, I'd use `flatten` at the end, instead of `map`.

Answer (score 1):

The logical way is to consume the first 3 ltr word, then lookahead for the
next one.

Since you want both words together, you'd capture each one then join
them together after each match.  `\b([a-z]{2,3})(?=(\s+[a-z]{2,3})\b)`

```
 \b 
 ( [a-z]{2,3} )                # (1)
 (?=
      (                             # (2 start)
           \s+ 
           [a-z]{2,3} 
      )                             # (2 end)
      \b 
 )
```

The next logical way (though, not intuitive) is to lookahead for the
combined 2 words, then consume the first one to advance the match
position.  `(?=\b(([a-z]{2,3})\s+[a-z]{2,3})\b)\2`

This way lets you just grab group 1 without the need to join.

```
 (?=
      \b 
      (                             # (1 start)
           ( [a-z]{2,3} )                # (2)
           \s+ 
           [a-z]{2,3} 
      )                             # (1 end)
      \b 
 )
 \2
```